# Javascript Array not showing up as an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have an array like so:

```
var data = {"result":"success","ids":["00000","54321","123","22222","11111","55555","33333","abc123","123abc","12345","44444"]}
localStorage.ids = data.ids;
```

But now when I do:

```
angular.forEach(localStorage.ids, function(id, key) {
    console.log(id);
});
```

I get like:

```
0
0
0
0
0
,
5
4
3
```

And so on.

When I `console.log(JSON.stringify(localStorage.ids));` I get:

```
"00000,54321,123,22222,11111,55555,33333,abc123,123abc,12345,44444"
```

Does anyone know why this would happen?

Comment: It looks to me like either some code you've omitted is stingifying `localStorage.ids` before the `forEach` loop, or angular's `forEach` doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

localStorage stores only strings.

```
localStorage.setItem('ids', JSON.stringify(data.ids)); // to save

var ids = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('ids')); // to get
```